# preprocessor macro to make set of numbers

Tags: c++11, macros, preprocessor

I want to create a macro that will create a shared pointer to unordered set.

```
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_set>

#define MAKE_SET (x) make_shared<type_raw_set>(type_raw_set{x});

using std::make_shared;
using std::shared_ptr;
using std::unordered_set;

typedef const unordered_set<unsigned> type_raw_set;
typedef shared_ptr<type_raw_set> type_set;

type_set Snake = MAKE_SET(1,5,9,12,14,16,19,23,27,30,32,34) // does not compile
```

how do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a variable number of arguments to a macro requires using a variadic macro:

```
#define MAKE_SET(...) \
  make_shared<type_raw_set>(type_raw_set{__VA_ARGS__});
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, however double braces are not needed, since `type_raw_set{}` is a temporary object supplied to make_shared.

Comment: Hmm, I vaguely recalled braced-init working differently.  But then again my usual work hasn't yet given me sufficiently-new compilers to use it yet, and it does work locally, so clearly I'm wrong on that.  :-)  Will update the answer to reduce future-reader confusion.